# Java Singleton Thread class object

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a class as below

```
public class JobThread implements Runnable {

    private JobService jobService;
    private long interval;

    public JobThread(JobService jobService, long interval) {
        this.jobService = jobService;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      // some stuff
    }
}
```

This is class is doing the work as expected. But i want to make this class as singleton class. Basically this class is consumed by multiple projects through its jar file. The parameters of this class are project specific. However it is meaningless if they have multiple instances of this class as per business logic. So i'm thinking to make this as singleton. So that they cannot create multiple objects for this class. Can some one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use same singleton in many different projects?

Comment: No. One singleton for each project. Multiple copies of jars implies multiple singleton classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the singleton class rules to make it a singleton class.

```
 public class JobThread implements Runnable
{

  private static JobService jobService;
  private static long interval;
  private static JobThread myObj;

  static
  {
    myObj = new JobThread ();
  }

  private JobThread ()
  {

  }

   @Override public void run ()
  {
    //some stuff
  }

  public static JobThread getInstance (JobService jobService_p,
                       long interval_p)
  {
    jobService = jobService_p;
    interval = interval_p;
    return myObj;
  }
}
```

Comment: Parameters inside `getInstance()` is unnecessary. These values are `static`, so it's better to create without parameters and add `setter`s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard singleton pattern. In the createInstance method you can try to acquire a lock if it is not available createInstance can throw exception else return the object

```
Lock lock = ...;
public JobInstance createInstance()
{

    if (lock.tryLock()) {
            //Create instance of your object here

      } else {
          // throw object already exist exception
    }
}
```

you have to release the lock when run method is done also in the finalize to ensure proper cleanup if run crashes without releasing the lock.